# How can I export a Module from Wikipedia to my self hosted MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have a template

http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php?title=Template:Cita_conferenza

Which invokes a LUA module:

http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/wiki/Modulo:Citazione

I have found informations on that module here, but it's not specified how to import it on my wiki.. any hint?

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo:Citazione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *[Special:Export](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciale:Esporta)* and export *Modulo:Citazione* with the "Includi i template" option. Then go to *[Special:Import](http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/wiki/Speciale:Importa)* of your wiki and import the XML file saved on export.

Also, you need to activate the extension *[Parser functions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions)* to enable the parser functions `{{#if:}}`, `{{ifeq:}}` and `{{#switch:}}`.